# What is the meaning of the error rate in Neural networks?

Tags: neural-networks, backpropagation

I'm a beginner with neural networks. I get that the error should be low. **But what does that number really mean?**
I created a simple neural network which has a error of 1.5. Is that too high? What are the consequences?

Answer (score 2):

The error basically signifies how well your network is performing on a certain (training/testing/validation) set. Having a low error is good, will having a higher error is certainly bad. The error is calculated through a [loss function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_function), of which there are several.

One of these for example is the [Mean Squared Error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error), which will calculate the distance between the wanted input and the real input, and squaring this value.

So if your network is outputting `[0.5]` for example, but you want it to output `[0]`. Your error will be `(0.5 - 0)^2 = 0.25`. But this error is just used to signify how well the network is performing.

During backpropagation, the network uses something called [error responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation#Loss_function) through which it calculates how much it should change connection weights and biases.

About your 1.5 error: this is fairly high! Normally, your error should be between `0` and `1`. A 'good' error is anywhere between `0` and `0.05`.

Answer (score -1):

The error is a measure of the difference between what the ANN predicts and the real Label of data.
for example for a simple "And" inputs and label(output) is like:

input1-input2-output
  0          0          0
  0          1          0
  1          0          0
  1          1          1

if for example, the network predicts `1` for inputs `0` and `0` it's wrong and it will be added to the Error.
so basically Error is a measure showing how much the network is Wrong!